# Why do I need to remove build directory after changing something in a Qt .pro file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

Every single time I change something in a Qt .pro file (add a new source file, change compile flags, etc...), my changes do not take effect. I am using Qt Creator. The same thing happens on windows (MSVC compiler) and Mac. If i remove build directory, it's ok then. (not counting wasted time for full rebuild)

Could be a bug but as it sounds so trivial it rather feels like I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you change somethng in a *.pro file, you have to re-run qmake on the project, to refresh the files in Qt Creator. You don't need to delete your build folder every time.

But when you delete the build folder, Qt automatically run qmake on the project before running the compilation. Your solution works, but it's a bit overkill ;)

[image: qtcreator build menu]

This menu is also available when right-clicking on the project

Comment: A-ha! Thanks, that's helpful! What might be the rationale behind Qt Creator not running qmake on it's own? Indeed it recognizes the change, adds referenced files to the file browser panel, I implicitly thought it should re-run qmake as necessary.

Comment: I don't see any reason preventing qmake being run automatically. But I imagine there is plenty: too difficult to develop, not so useful specially for big projects, better control on project configuration... And doing too much work automatically can sometimes be counter-productive: forcing developers to run qmake manually make them learn what qmake is actually doing, when it necessary to run it, etc.